# Difference between c and code tags

Tags: c#, xml-comments

In C# xml comments, what is the difference between the tags below?

```
1. <c> 
2. <code>
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean in the xml code comments (for intellisense?)

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because the original question is not clear at all.

Comment: it didn't even mention xml comments; the assumption, based on the previous asp.net tag (now removed) is that you are talking about html, where only one of those tags is even defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [tags in xml comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), `c` is like back-ticks in StackOverflow, while `code` is more like code blocks.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the <c>SomeMethod</c> method of the <c>Program</c> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">A string.</param>
/// <example>
/// You can use this method like this:
/// <code>
/// string x = SomeMethod("foobar");
/// Console.WriteLine(x);
/// </code>
/// </example>
static string SomeMethod(string s){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: + 1 for the link and very descriptive answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<c>Your code sample.</c>
```

Indicates a short segment of code. You will use the c tag to draw attention to particular words, phrases or code in the resulting documentation. You will nest c tags within other tags.

```
<code>Your code sample.</code>
```

The code tag is similar to the  tag, but it is intended to illustrate a true code usage example. The code tag is generally enclosed within an  tag set (see below).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean in code comments, then [`<code>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8hahtxf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (generally used within [`<example>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w4cf933%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) represents multiple lines of illustrative code, where-as [`<c>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te6h7cxs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) represents just a single term to be written in a code font.

To use stackoverflow/markdown as a comparison, they are exactly the same as `inline code` in the middle of a paragrah, vs

```
a multi-line
code sample that
appears formatted separately
```